# Irreducibility proof for any prime number

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Prove that for any prime number p and any natural number n,  $f(x)=x^n - p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: More generally if $\ (n,m)=1=(a,p)\ $ then $\ x^n + a p^m\ $ is irreducible over $\,\Bbb Q\,$ by Dumas's Criterion. Learn about the Newton polygon to go further.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use Eisenstein's criterion.